# Call an external Web services in Magento

Tags: web-services, magento

I need to use external web services on my magento project.
Can any one guide me how to call a simple web service in magento?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: What type of web services... REST etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of Zend framework is available which includes an [HTTP client](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.http.client.html).  But there is nothing to stop you using any existing PHP method, like [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or [file_get_contents with an URI](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).   Personally I prefer [Guzzle](http://guzzlephp.org/) for it's persistent connections and caching.

---

Addendum.  Since you seem to require a SOAP client perhaps you can use the well known [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php).  Pass the URI of a relevant WSDL file to the constructor, it can be local or remote.
This has nothing to do with Magento of course, it is plain PHP, if you have a specific question about accessing SOAP then please start a new question.

Comment: Thanks clockworkgeek for your reply. But I dont understand where to put this code. from where I should call a method and where to include the .wsdl file?

Comment: I cannot say where you should call from except to say, wherever is appropriate.  I would imagine somewhere in a model if you are keeping with the MVC pattern.